# Install ubuntu in one specefic drive on win10

Tags: system-installation

I have win10 installed on my laptop, with 5 drive C,D,E,F,G...
I'm gonna install ubuntu14.4 beside win10 ... Wanna install on drive G: 200GB, but the installation wizard does not show my derives ... 
How can I select drive G for installation ? 
Are all my drives will be safe on windows after I installed Ubuntu?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  Please look carefully here, there are many posts from people destroying their Windows installation when trying to do this.

Comment: @StephenRauch You are scaring the guy! There are many reasons to want to do so, I myself one day had these OSs stacked sequentially: DOS, Win98, NT4 workstation, NT4 Server, 2000 Pro, 2000 Server, Linux Suse, Linux Redhat, and I couldn't get past some prerequisite to install Novel Netware on the final partition of my "whopping" 20 GBytes disk :D :D Experiment, experiment, experiment...

Comment: @StephenRauch I know there is VirtualBox, but you can't deny the guy rights to enjoy full physical hands on!

Comment: @MK Yes, you may have done that.  But the question remains, why?  In this day and age virtualization works really well.  What does Dual Boot do for you that virtualization does not?  I am only suggesting to answer that question before risking your main machine.

Comment: @StephenRauch Like I said I know there is VBox, but you won't get reliable peripheral connections with it, for one. You also can't measure real performance of your hardware, if you are considering to move from Satya's corrupted dreams of an OS to the open land of Ubuntu.

Comment: Because I need full memory access an CPU process. I aware of this risk ... I just want to install on separate drive from win drive , not alongside win ..

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible that installer is showing your drives but you can't recognize them? Have you made sure you selected "Manual" when asked about partitioning options?

Is it possible for you to post a screenshot (even a camera-shot would do)?

If you do install Ubuntu on one drive, yes, other partitions won't be touched. You will also get an option to boot into Windows, beside Ubuntu.

Comment: My drives on win10 :

https://pasteboard.co/HsmXjH2.jpg

During Ubuntu installation shows my 1Tb HDD but no drive:

https://pasteboard.co/HsmYm91.jpg

Comment: This could one of two: you selected a partitioning option other than manual, or, there is a dynamic overlay on your disk that Ubuntu cannot read. If the second is your case, I advise you to back off. Use VirtualBox.

Comment: I selected something else ... ! What is that dynamic overlay ? How can I remove ..?

Comment: @Nicefff You cannot, without destroying your existing data.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_drive_overlay is a software layer embedded into your harddisk at vendor factory or by an OS installer, that enables some advanced features in the running OS like resizing partitions without 3rd party software, for one. Most OEM vendors today like to put it on pre-loaded PCs/Laptops to help with OS recovery.

Comment: @Nicefff When an OS is unable to deal with that dynamic overlay, it sees the harddisk empty, or sometimes "corrupted".

Comment: May it fix the problem if I use Fdisk for partitioning my drive G: ?!,

Comment: @Nicefff Nope. Any workaround will kill your data. Please use VirtualBox > https://www.virtualbox.org.